# Are enums really constants ? Shouldn't the data members of enum be declared final by default?

Tags: java, enums

According to the Java tutorial on the [Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of **predefined constants**. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it.

I agree that the values are predefined. But are they really **constants**?

The `enum` values can be changed, by changing the values of the data members. So, can they logically be called constants ?

Assuming I have an `enum` as follows:

```
public enum Color
{
    BLACK("0x000000"), WHITE("0xffffff");

    Color(String rgbValue)
    {
        this.rgbValue = rgbValue;
    }

    private String rgbValue;

    public String getRgbValue()
    {
        return this.rgbValue;
    }

    public void setRgbValue(String rgbValue)
    {
        this.rgbValue = rgbValue;
    }
}
```

In the above `enum`, I can change the value of `rgbValue`, by using a setter. If I execute the following set of statements, the state of `BLACK` is changed.

```
System.out.println(Color.BLACK.getRgbValue());
Color.BLACK.setRgbValue("0x000010");
System.out.println(Color.BLACK.getRgbValue());
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
0x000000
0x000010
```

So can we really refer to `enum` values as constants? Shouldn't the state of the `enum` value be prevented from changing? Shouldn't the data members in `enum` be declared as `final` by default, so that the `enum` can be truly called a constant ?

If the state of the `enum` is not conserved, then what is the difference between a normal `class` and an `enum` apart from the predefined number of objects that are created?

Or is there a specific reason, why the Java designers have kept this functionality ?

Comment: Discussions about language design choices probably aren't best suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Based on the [specification for questions suited to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I'd say that this question is too broad, and would be better suited to [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) which has a different [question specification](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is immutable, and what is `static final` by default, are the enum values (as to their visibility modifier, ie `public`, `private` or default, it is inherited from the declaration of the enum itself).

But these values are classes in their own right; and as such, this immutability does not hold for their *instance variables*, if any.

In order for the *full* enum to be immutable:

- their instance members must also be `final`,
- and these instance members must also, by themselves, be immutable.

In the most trivial case of enum usage (ie, `public class MyEnum { VALUE1, VALUE2 }`), instance variable immutability is not a concern, since they have none.

But as soon as you add instance variables to enums, the same constraint to these instance variables apply, as they do for any other Java class (even if said classes are `final`). Since, ultimately, enum instances are classes by their own right. They just happen to be singletons, `final`, and `extends Enum<ThemSelves>`.

In your example, your `rgbValue` must therefore be `final`. This way, and since `String` is an immutable class, your enum will "truly" be immutable.

Strangely enough, the best default immutability you can think of are found in... Interfaces:

```
public interface Foo
{
    int bar = 3; // bar is "public", "static" AND "final" by default
}
```

Comment: Nice. I've learned something new from your answer (about the best default immutability). But I'm afraid this works only for primitives. What if we change `int bar = 3` with some custom object ? The object may not be immutable itself....

Comment: @kocko this is exactly what I said: the immutability does not hold for instance variables; if said variable references are final but the referenced object is not, you're doomed ;)

Answer (score 4):

`Color.BLACK` is a constant in the sense that across your application (class loader to be more specific), there is only one instance of your enum that corresponds to `Color.BLACK` and `Color.BLACK` will always refer to that instance.

You can't write: `Color.BLACK = Color.WHITE;` for example.

But an enum instance is not necessarily immutable as you have found out.

It is exactly the same as when you write:

```
public static final List MY_LIST = new ArrayList();
```

`MY_LIST` will always refer to the same list, but you can add to or remove from that list.

Comment: There is quite a difference between a reference being `final` and the object behind that reference being immutable but yeah, that is the essence :p

Answer (score 1):

Using the elements from an enumeration means that you have (let's say) a pool of **constant** references to a bunch of objects in the memory. Nowhere is said that these objects have to be **immutable**, therefore you can change their state. But the reference `Color.BLACK` will be one and the same all the time.